# Can't set a checkbox checked | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am currently discovering JavaScript and I have some problems...
I want to to set a check box to checked by using Js, but it doesn't seem to work. :/

Here is the HTML code:

```
<td><input id="jm" type="checkbox" onClick="check(1)"></td>
<td><input id="conference" type="checkbox" name="casmaret"></td>
```

Here is the Js code:

```
 function check(valeur)

     switch (valeur)
     {
         case 1:
                  document.getElementById("jm").checked = true;
                  document.getElementById("conference").checked = true;
                  break;
      }
 }
```

I simplified it, but the fact is, I want to check some other checkbox by checking one checkbox. When I look over the debugger in Chrome, the function executes, but it doesn't change anything...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, you code works as you described it should: http://jsbin.com/uxatoj/1/edit

Comment: Yes, it's look like it work's, but on my page, it doesn't :(

Comment: What is ´valeur´ and can't declared...

Comment: miss { !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `{` after your `function check(valeur)`:

```
function check(valeur)
{
     switch (valeur)
     {
         case 1:
                  document.getElementById("jm").checked = true;
                  document.getElementById("conference").checked = true;
                  break;
     }
}
```